# Postgresql - how to drop a trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

A while ago I've created a trigger in Postgresql, update_user, which sets the update_date to `now()` for table users. Now I want to drop this trigger.

The following queries don't work:

```
drop trigger update_user;
drop trigger update_user on users;
```

I get the following error back:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
```

How can I drop this trigger?

Comment: drop trigger triggername on tablename; should work... How odd.

Answer (score 0):

I made a connection using pgadmin, and then dropped the trigger. The problem was I can only use ssh to connect to the server, and I didn't know how to make that connection at first. I've just found a way to tunnel the connection via ssh.

```
ssh -fNg -L 5555:localhost:5432 {username}@{domain.com}
```

Comment: You can also just `ssh username@domain.com psql` to run `psql` directly on the remote host. Much more convenient than an ssh tunnel.

Comment: But how is this connected to the syntax error?